# Scala recursive val behaviour

Tags: scala, scalac

What do you think prints out?

```
val foo: String = "foo" + foo
println(foo)

val foo2: Int = 3 + foo2
println(foo2)
```

Answer:

```
foonull
3
```

Why? Is there a part in specification that describes/explains this?

EDIT: To clarify my astonishment - I do realize that `foo` is undefined at `val foo: String = "foo" + foo` and that's why it has a default value `null` (zero for integers). But this doesn't seem very "clean", and I see opinions here that agree with me. I was hoping that compiler would stop me from doing something like that. It does make sense in some particular cases, such as when defining `Stream`s which are lazy by nature, but for strings and integers I would expect either stopping me due to reassignment to val or telling me that I'm trying to use an undefined value, just like as if I wrote `val foo = whatever` (given that `whatever` was never defined).

To further complicate things, @dk14 points out that this behaviour is only present for values represented as fields and doesn't happen within blocks, e.g.

```
val bar: String = {
  val foo: String = "foo" + foo // error: forward reference extends...
  "bar"
}
```

Comment: What behaviour would you expect?

Comment: Compiler telling me "reassigning to val" or something like that. Or telling me that it doesn't know what `foo` is (because compiler's lexical analysis didn't yet store this token since it wasn't fully defined yet). Definitely not giving it temporary value `null` which sounds more like JavaScript than Scala (with undefined instead of null of course).

Comment: @slouc also notice the difference in behavior when replacing the `val`s with `def`s.

Comment: @fxlae Of course, and that's completely logical. But `val`s behaving this way seems a bit "broken". I would like to trust the `val`s to be really immutable, which means that `foo` either has some never-changing value or doesn't exist at all. Not to have value null here and xy there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, see the [SLS Section 4.2](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variable-declarations-and-definitions).

`foo` is a `String` which is a reference type. It has a default value of `null`. `foo2` is an `Int` which has a default value of 0.

In both cases, you are referring to a val which has not been initialized, so the default value is used.

Comment: OK, so it's the same as if e.g. you are trying to use a field within some abstract class whose value has not been yet defined in the subclass (due to order of linearization). But shouldn't this definition of `val` be caught by the compiler? It's a clear re-declaration of a `val`.

Comment: It's not a re-declaration of a val. The val is only declared once, but it's being used before it has been initialized.

Comment: Exactly, and compiler could have warned us about this. It should be the same as saying `val foo = whatever` (given that `whatever` is not defined anywhere). But I guess what happens is "OK, here we have initialization of a val, let's create it and assign it a null value until we finish the initialization".

Comment: @slouc hear ya, unfortunately, scala is not as safe as let's say Haskell because of compromises with Java.  There is a safe subset called Scalazzi and some of sbt/scalac-plugins can give you more warnings/errors: https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover

Answer (score 1):

Scala's `Int` is backed by a primitive type (`int`) underneath, and its default value (before initialization) is 0.

On the other hand, `String` is an `Object` which is indeed `null` when not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases `foo` resp. `foo2` have their default values according to the JVM specification. That's `null` for a reference type and `0` for an `int` or `Int` - as Scala spells it.

Comment: It's actually the JMM (Java Memory Model) that defines this

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, scala is not as safe as let's say Haskell because of compromises with Java's OOP model ("Object-oriented meets Functional"). There is a safe subset of Scala called [Scalazzi](http://yowconference.com.au/slides/yowwest2014/Morris-ParametricityTypesDocumentationCodeReadability.pdf) and some of sbt/scalac-plugins can give you more warnings/errors:

https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover ([doesn't check](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover/issues/286) for the case you've found though)

Returning back to your case, this happens only for values represented as fields and doesn't happen when you're inside a function/method/block:

```
scala> val foo2: Int = 3 + foo2 
foo2: Int = 3

scala> {val foo2: Int = 3 + foo2 }
<console>:14: error: forward reference extends over definition of value foo2
       {val foo2: Int = 3 + foo2 }
                            ^

scala> def method = {val a: Int = 3 + a}
<console>:12: error: forward reference extends over definition of value a
       def method = {val a: Int = 3 + a}
```

The reason of this situation is integration with Java as `val` compiles to the `final` field in JVM, so Scala saves all initialization specifics of JVM classes (I believe it's part of JSR-133: Java Memory Model). Here is the more complicated example that explains this behavior:

```
 scala> object Z{ val a = b; val b = 5}
 <console>:12: warning: Reference to uninitialized value b
   object Z{ val a = b; val b = 5}
                     ^
 defined object Z

 scala> Z.a
 res12: Int = 0
```

So, here you can see the warning that you didn't see in the first place.

Comment: @slouc you're welcome. I added clarification about why this behaviour is taking place

Comment: Great, thanks. I already accepted an answer before you came along, but I do admit this one is more informative.